# Best places in India to visit in September first half

Tags: india, tours, weather-and-climate, destinations

Which are the places in India to visit during September first half. More interested in northern India. Especially Shimla - Kulu - Manali. Will it be a good climate there in September.? Is it raining or extreme cold climate. I would like to go places which are cold and covered with snow but with a good weather to have a blast..

Answer (score 2):

> places which are cold and covered with snow but with a good weather to have a blast

Very very tricky. September is within the monsoon period and I don't think you will escape rain even in the hill stations. Snow will be highly improbable unless you decide to venture towards higher altitudes in the Himalayas.

The best option I can think of is Ladakh, if you want to explore the unexplored wilderness. It isn't your typical holiday place, but is sincerely a very nice place to go.

Comment: Like you said in higher altitudes thats what i mentioned about kulu-manali-shimla because they also belongs to the himalayas